# How to fix a non static function

Tags: c++

```
case 5: {
        system("cls");

        gotoxy(50, 22);

        cout << "Enter the Driving License Number to search : ";

        cin.ignore(); 

        cin.getline(srch, 14);

        system("cls");

        drivinglicense::record_searchdrivinglicense(srch);

        break;
    }
```

error that is being displayed is :

> a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

it is showing error somewhere in line of `drivinglicense::record_searchdrivinglicense(srch);`

Please help how could I solve this error

Comment: You code is too mininal, pease show a [mre] with emphasis on the reproducible part.

Comment: gotoxy? cls? is that Borland under Mess Dos? The best fix would be to kill it with fire then...

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to mix IO libraries. I'm not sure how well iostreams and conio play together.

Comment: Please, change your title to e.g. "How to fix a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object?" (I would've done myself but there is a pending edit.) Please, take the [tour] (what you didn't yet) and have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The compiler tells you that `drivinglicense::record_searchdrivinglicense(srch);` is a call to a static function, but `record_searchdrivinglicense` is not static so it needs an instance to be called on.

Now the choice is yours. Is it supposed to be static, but you forgot to mark it as such? Or did you want to call it on an instance of `drivinglicense`?